# List Iterator to delete last element

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm having a problem deleting the last element of my list. It deletes the second to last element for some reason. There was a very useful post on this site about how to do it and it got me this far but I'm still having problems. I just don't quite understand how this doesn't work?

If I changed `iter++` to `++iter`, I get an error trying to access invalid information when I delete the last element.

```
std::list<Recipe>::iterator iter = recipes.begin();

while(iter != recipes.end() )
{
    if(iter->GetName() == buffer)
    {
        recipes.erase(iter++);
    }
    else
    {
        iter++;
    }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: what was the useful post?

Comment: The code looks right. Better, though, is to use `recipes.remove([buffer](Recipe const & r) { return r.GetName() == buffer; });`.

Comment: does `GetName` return a `string`? If yes, may be use `strcmp` or `std::string::compare`?

Comment: The comparison is fine. I'm not sure if I should use remove or erase? I don't really know the difference?

I can't find the useful post anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you call remove an iterator in c++ it will become invalid as an iterator, you should not do it this way..

You are right to use erase, but you should assign erase to the iter as erase returns an iterator to the the next element:

```
iter = recipes.erase(iter);
```

So this code should work:

```
while(iter != recipes.end() )
{
    if(iter->GetName() == buffer)
    {
        iter = recipes.erase(iter);
    }
    else
    {
        iter++;
    }

}
```

[list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/)

Now could very well be, that you equality is incorrect we do not know what buffer is or what GetName() returns, could you perhaps have two of those?

Comment: @Bill Erase returns an iterator pointing to the next element after the element you just erased..no need to increment, this should work fine.

Comment: This still deletes the second to last element. The comparison works just fine.. It just has a problem deleting the LAST element of a list.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks! I was using the wrong message when trying to access the list box that this information was held in.